# Include URL in php

Tags: php, html

My form create by php script and between teo file:

1. index.php
2. header.php

In `index.php`, i try in 
...

```
<div class="art-header-png"></div>
<div class="art-header-jpeg"></div>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
</div>
<div class="art-nav">
<div class="l"></div>
<div class="r"></div>
```

and my header.php

```
<div class="art-logo">
    <h1 id="name-text" class="art-logo-name"><a href="#">Your Title Goes Here</a></h1>
    <div id="slogan-text" class="art-logo-text">Your Slogan Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

But it didn't show content inside `header.php`.
How can i make it work?

Comment: display nothing.. izit can use <?php include("header.php");?> to link between the page?

Comment: display nothing meaning the rendered index.php is blank?

Comment: means i cant display the content of header.php in index.php..

Comment: do you get anything after `include`

Comment: nope.. i get nothing after include

Comment: means that you did not specify the correct path.

Comment: change include to require to make sure that you inserting header.php

Comment: where is header.php located relative to index.php?

Comment: i stil cant show the content of header.php in index.php..

Answer (score 0):

First thing, either place header.php in the same folder as index.php or specify the correct path relative to index.php when you are using include (same apply to require).

[PHP Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

also check to see if your php is configured correctly as well.  Save  the following line of code in a php file.  Run it and see if you get php window:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```